# Need Advice on How To Set ComboBox and JXDatePicker back to original setting after clearing screen

Tags: java, swing, date, combobox

I have a jpanel with some textfields, comboboxes, and jxdatepickers and a table which holds the values to those fields.  Now, I want to select a row from the table and edit the values by repopulating them in order to change them. I have the following code for when I click the "edit" button after I have selected a row:

```
 private void jButton_editActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   File h = new File("caseInfoTemp.txt");
   BufferedWriter buf;
   try {
        buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(h, true));
        int row = jTable_caseInfo.getSelectedRow();
            for(int j = 0; j < jTable_caseInfo.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                buf.write(jTable_caseInfo.getValueAt(row, j).toString() + "\t");
            }
            buf.newLine();
            buf.close();
   }catch (Exception e){    
}


    try{
       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("caseInfoTemp.txt");
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
       String line;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           String[] delims = line.split("\t");
           jSpinner_case.setValue(Integer.parseInt(delims[0]));
           jTextField_case.setText(delims[1]);
           //fix to set combobox to what was chosen
           jComboBox_client.setPopupVisible(true);
           //fix to set datepicker to what was chosen
           jXDatePicker_openDate.setDate(null);


       }
        }catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {

}                                            
}
```

I have the //comment lines explaining what I would like to do, but I do not know which option to select to get the "string" values from the text file to populate the comboboxes and the jxdatepicker fields.  I can only get the textfields to populate correctly.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found to work:

jComboBox_client.setSelectedItem(delims[2]);

now I just need to find the right way to setDate of jxdatepicker back to date picked.